# How to get data-id from button on the modal?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have created a data show page in PHP and I want to modify particular data. Then, I click a button for modifying the data, after click popup modal of updating data form. So, I don't understand how to get the data id on modal to update particular data.

Button for open modal:

```
<button 
title="Edit Sub Category" 
class="btn btn-success edit_subcategory" 
dataid="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

Modal for updating data:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EDIT_SUBCATEGORY" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Sub Category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body update_subcategory1">
                    <?php                               
                        $id = $_POST['dataid']; **<!-- Here i want data id-->**
                        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wm_subcategory WHERE id='$id'");
                        if($result->num_rows > 0){
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                ?>
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["subcate_id"] ?>" name="subcate_id" class="form-control">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subcate_name">Category Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row["subcate_name"] ?>" name="subcate_name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <?php 
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="update_subcategory" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js getting data from modal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.edit_subcategory').on('click', function () {
        Id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#EDIT_SUBCATEGORY').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the id using the jQuery's [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.edit_subcategory').on('click', function () {
        var modalDiv = $('#EDIT_SUBCATEGORY');

        // Get id
        var id = $(this).attr('dataid');

        // Store the id and show modal        
        modalDiv.data('selectedId', id).modal('show');
    });
});
```

Then, on the modal's submit button click:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    // Get the stored id
    var id = $('#EDIT_SUBCATEGORY').data('selectedId');

    // Continue ...
});
```

Comment: Here i want data id value  $id = $_POST['dataid']; on modal.